# How to standardize (archetyping) the projects in .NET?

Tags: .net, project

I come from Java World and this was quiet simple to create a simple way to develop projects.  I needed just to create a small set of Maven Archetypes and institutionalize it inside a context, for example a company that I work.

However .NET is a world that I seldom visit and I would like to know how to create templates of projects?

Comment: I don't think there is an exact corollary. There are a few options - you could create a visual studio project or item template, NuGet packages for specific requirements / pieces of a framework, or Roslyn analyzers for code style checking.

Comment: It is called "template" in visual studio.  You get to choose from many precooked ones when you create a new project or add a new item to a project.  Making your own is easy with Project > Export Template.